# Magento 2.3 How to include header/footer into admin notification emails?

Tags: magento2, admin, email

I have Magento2.3 setup and all transactional emails are working fine.

**In magento, there are several emails related to admin events like,'
new admin user created, admin user change password, forgot password for admin user, etc...**

In this kind of emails, it will not include the header/footer. it is Magento's default feature I think.

**I want to include header/footer into the emails fire after admin user add/update/forgot pass.**

**I want to use header/footer into 
"vendor\magento\module-user\view\adminhtml\email\user_notification.html"
 and all emails regarding admin notifications.**

If anyone has any idea please share.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

To Add the header in email template, you can include (Appropriate position)

> {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

And for footer,

> {{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}

**Note:** For reference check below file path in Magento 2 installation directory,

> vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Sales/email/creditmemo_new.html

Comment: if we iclude header/footer with your idea it gives error as "Error filtering template: Template file 'header.html' is not found."

Comment: Probably, In transactional emails Default header Or Footer template is not set.